# Unable to show loading GIF in asp.net update panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

The following is the code I have written to show loading GIF in my asp.net page.I have a popup extender called pnladd. I have considered it as the section for the update panel. When I try running in localhost, it shows no progress i.e. loading gif doesnot appear while update progress happens.

If i put the  tag inside the update panel i get runtime error-

> " An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends."

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPopup" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="UpdateProgress"
    PopupControlID="UpdateProgress" BackgroundCssClass="modalPopupBG" />

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/waiting.gif"
            AlternateText="Processing" runat="server" />
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlMilestoneType" CssClass="centered" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalpopupHierarchy" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG" Drag="true" PopupControlID="pnlAdd" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" TargetControlID="lblTarget">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlAdd" Style="display: none" Width="500px" runat="server">
                <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
                    <div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader" style="height: 30px; width: 500px; vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; text-align: center;">

                        <asp:Label ID="lblPopupHeader" runat="server"> </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PopupBody" style="float: center; margin-left: 40px">
                        <br />

                        <table align="center" style="height: 75px; width: 348px">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top">Name
                                </td>
                                <td class="validation">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>*
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Name" ControlToValidate="txtName" ValidationGroup="addValidation" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top">Description
                                </td>
                                <td class="validation">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="footer" align="center">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnOkay" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="addValidation" CssClass="BtnAddCP submitIcon" OnClick="btnOkay_Click" Visible="true" Style="width: 80px; text-align: left" />

                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="submitIcon BtnAddCP" ValidationGroup="addValidation" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" Visible="false" Style="width: 80px; text-align: left" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" CssClass="BtnAddCP cancelIcon" Style="width: 80px; text-align: left" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Can someone help how to resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: U have added `ScriptManager` in the Master page?

Comment: I tried your code its working fine. On which button click you are facing this problem?

Comment: all three buttons ! okay,update and cancel.....not showing the gif after click

Comment: Is image path correct? Are you getting processing label?

Comment: Ali thanks for  your time..it works fine! I need another help on this...I must not let the user to do any clicks while the GIF loads. Can u help on this??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98103/discussion-between-aliasgar-rajpiplawala-and-user3837883).